# How to include winscard.lib in a qt project

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm having problems including winscard.lib in my QT project.
I have windows 10 x64 and I downloaded the microsoft sdk V7.1 because I didn't have the winscard library in the microsoft sdk v10.

Now, my .pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = NFC
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    globs.cpp \
    newcard.cpp \
    newcircuitnumber.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    globs.h \
    newcard.h \
    newcircuitnumber.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui \
    newcard.ui \
    newcircuitnumber.ui


INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include"
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\IA64"
LIBS += -winscard -lz
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSqlQuery>

#include "globs.h"  
#include "qt_windows.h"
#include "winnt.h" 
#include "winscard.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);   

    SCARDCONTEXT cardContext;
    LPWSTR mszReaders;
    DWORD dwReaders;


    SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER,NULL,NULL,&cardContext);
    dwReaders = SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE;
    SCardListReadersW(cardContext,NULL,(LPWSTR)&mszReaders,&dwReaders);

    QByteArray buffer;
    wchar_t *it = mszReaders;

    while(*it !='\0')
    {
        buffer.append(QChar(*it));
        *it++;
    }
   qDebug()<<buffer;
}
```

The error I get when I try to compile are the following:

Errors

[image]

Can somebody point me to a solution? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Would be nice if you translate the error message...

Comment: Are you trying to create a 32bit application with a 64bit library?

Comment: Maybe write it like `LIBS += -lwinscard -lz` instead? Note the `-l` at front.

Comment: @user1810087 no, the compiler is MSVC2017 64bit. anyway I din't give that warning a lot of attention since it's just a warning. I think the probelm is that I'm not linking the libraries in the right way. The errors say "reference to extern symbol SCardEstablishContext unresolved in the function.... " it means it hasn't found the library.

Comment: If it cannot find the reference to a symbol, it does not mean it cannot find the library, **it also can mean you want to mix 32bit with 64bit where it also cannot reference the correct symbols**...

Comment: @vahancho I tried it but nothing changhed...

Comment: @user1810087 PC is an AMD 64 bit, the compiler is MSVC20!7 64bit adn the path of the lib is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\IA64. Is it possible that the lib is 32 bit anyway?